# Solaris 11 Not Able To Install PKG File

Tags: solaris, command, pkg

I am trying to install a .pkg file on a Solaris 11 Intel machine and am faced with the following error:

```
pkg install: The following pattern(s) did not match any allowable packages.  Try
using a different matching pattern, or refreshing publisher information:
```

The command I am using to install the package is:

```
pkg install <package name>
```

I have set full permissions on the package using chmod 777  and have also run the pkg update command with a reboot.

Does anyone know what the problem here may be?

Comment: Please show us the actual command used. The error is telling you that the pattern you specified cannot be found, so we cannot help unless you tell us what you specified.

Comment: Sounds like the package you are trying to install is not available in your package repo.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54739/tspkginstall.html

Comment: Hi @terdon & jesse_b thank you for the feedback, I have moved a .pkg file onto the machine that has worked previously when it comes to installing on the Solaris 11 platform but on this particular machine, the install just keeps throwing the error highlighted above in the post. To install the .pkg file, I used the command "pkg install <package.pkg>". As I am trying to install a .pkg file, I assumed no repo would be required? Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: @jesse_b just tagging you as it did not allow me to do so in my original response! ^^

Comment: Thanks, but please ***edit*** your question and add all relevant information. Especially the actual name of the `package.pkg` and the _exact_ command you used. If you are installing from a local file, we need to know that too, and also if you are using a relative path to it or a full one.

Comment: @Help I don't think that's how the pkg command works.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine what type of package the file is.

Packages for the IPS package manager (the primary package manager in Solaris 11) usually end in .p5m, not .pkg, but that's just a convention, not a requirement.  If this is an IPS package, then you would need to get the actual package name (`pkgrepo -s package.pkg list`), and do:

```
pkg install -g package.pkg actual/package/name
```

If it is instead a SVR4 package (the primary package manager in Solaris 2-10) you instead will need to use pkgadd to install it.